# Create a PowerBI measure to sum a text column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a column in my table that looks as follows

Table

```
Answer   Type
10     |  10
N/A    |   3
four   |   3
20     |  10
4      |  10
yes=1  |   3
```

I only want to sum the columns that have a type of 10

This is what I tried.

```
sum = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Answer]),filter('Table',Table[Type]=10))+0
```

I wanted the output to be a sum of 34, but I keep getting an error:

> The function sum can not work with values string

I can not change the datatype of the column as I use the text for a different calculation.

Could some one advise how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code

```
Only_int_sum =
CALCULATE (
    SUMX ( 'Table', IFERROR ( VALUE ( 'Table'[Answer] ), 0 ) ),
    'Table'[Type] = 10
)
```

PFA screenshot for reference

[image]